# Ultrasonic sensor option missing in Wait block in Labview

Tags: ev3, labview

I have hooked up the EV3 brick and the Ultrasonic sensor (on port 4) from the older mindstorms set 8527, and using the most recent Labview software on windows 7.

I am trying to test the model for distance and to stop a few cm from the wall. The WAIT block in Labview does NOT have an option for Ultrasonic Sensor, but has one for Infrared Sensor, which does not seem to work. Has anyone noticed this missing menu option?

*NOTE: The EV3 displays the distance in cm when the unltrasonic senor is connected to port 4 on the EV3.

Answer (score 3):

Once you download the block from the Lego site, you can import it into the LabVIEW by using the Tools tab and then Block Import, but first you need to be in an open program.  LabVIEW will prompt you to browse your folders to find the downloaded file, and then select Import at the bottom of the window.  Finally, you will need to close LabVIEW and reopen it to begin using the block in all of your programs.

Answer (score 1):

You can download US and gyro blocks from lego.com.